# Using storyboards and ARC for ios 4

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios5

I'm planning to write an iphone application which uses storyboards and ARC. As I know these features come with ios 5. The question is will my application run on ios 4 devices? If not, is there a way to run this application on ios 4 devices?

Thanks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ARC applications will run on iOS 4, but weak references aren't supported.

Storyboards are not available on iOS 4, period.

Answer (score 5):

No. There isn't. Those are iOS 5 features. While there may be possibilities to port ARC to iOS 4, storyboards are simply not usable on iOS 4.